# Custom CSS in Wordpress works fine, but if I add a class to the Advanced->Additional CSS in the block editor, it is ignored

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working with a client who has a custom Wordpress theme built by an agency. If I add Custom CSS in **Appearance->Customizer** (e.g. to override an existing style) then it works perfectly.  However, if I add a class name in **'Advanced->Additional CSS Classes'** in the Block Editor (i.e. via Edit Page - as shown in the attached image), then this has no effect.

I can't see any reference to the class I added in the inspector, but I know it's written correctly as if I insert it manually in the Inspector I can see it taking effect.

Can anyone offer any advice here?

[image: Adding Additional CSS class in Block Editor]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, try `.new-class` (with a period) in **Additional CSS Classes** then re-publish the post/page and check if the class name is applied.

If the block is a custom block, the issue could be caused by the block author not implementing [useBlockProps](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/#useblockprops) in either the JS `save()` function or [get_block_wrapper_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_block_wrapper_attributes/) in the `render_callback` for [dynamic blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/).

If this is the case, you would need to examine the blocks files and based on what you find, extend/update the existing `save()` or `render_callback` so that block props are included that contain the additional CSS class names, eg:

**JS** (static blocks)

```js
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function save() {
    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>...</div>
    );
}
```

**PHP** (dynamic blocks)

```php
function customblock_render_callback() {
    $wrapper_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes();

    return "<div $wrapper_attributes>...</div>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  The first option (adding the . before the class name) did not work.  Looking at the other option, I believe I am dealing with Static blocks. I can see the layout of these blocks in the Wordpress Theme File editor (under Templates->Blocks and then a bunch of php files for each custom block).  I can also see the blocks in the inc->register-blocks.php file.  But I am not sure where I should be looking for the save() function you mention? Any further guidance appreciated! Thanks

Comment: For clarity - I have found this, which is the exact same prob I am having, but perhaps explained more eloquently: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/css-class-does-not-apply-to-custom-block-acf-v5-8/

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. Given its ACF, it would be dynamic and you would be looking for the PHP file specified in either the `render_template` or `render_callback` as detailed in the [ACF documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_register_block_type/). NB. As of ACF 6.0  the [ACF block registration method](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-blocks-key-concepts/)  was updated - so it could be either the old or new way depending on how recent the block was authored.